# Create dynamic subteam in keybase from cmd line

Tags: powershell, keybase

I'm trying to create a subteam in keybase from the command line. If I explicitly mention the team names like this `keybase team create treehouse.hiring`. Subteam gets created without any error. But if I get the team name and subteam as a parameter, it doesn't seem to work. Below is my code.

```
keybase team create $teamName.$subTeamName
```

Error:

Error parsing command line arguments: team name argument required.

I even tried with these commands.

```
keybase team create --team=$teamName.$subTeamName
keybase team create --subteam=$teamName.$subTeamName
```

Comment: Try: `("--team={0}.{1}" -f $teamName,$subTeamName)`

Comment: `keybase team create "$teamName.$subTeamName"` Should work too.

Comment: Use https://github.com/Bill-Stewart/getargs/ (simply prefix your command with `getargs`) to see the _actual_ command line that PowerShell passes to the executable's command line.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @SantiagoSquarzon. Enclosing it with quotes worked for me.

Comment: Thank you @Bill_Stewart. I'll check out that link